# Which Perek of Tehillim did David Hamelech compose regarding when he and his army came back to Ziklag (Shmuel 1; 30,1)?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

I believe I read that there is a Perek of Tehillim (Psalms) that David Hamelech composed regarding when he and his army came back to Ziklag, and they saw that their wives and children were captured by Amalek, and with HaShem's help he persevered and they rescued their families.

(I tried googling with no success.) If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you thinking of Rashi on Psa. 18:29?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think there was a whole chapter, or at least verses of David being Boteach (Trust) that HaShem will make it end well. But maybe you're right. I was hoping that I remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this reference](http://strangeside.com/captives-redeeming/) to the incident.

> Dovid mounted a similar mission when an Amalek tribe raided his town,
>   Ziklag (I Shmuel ch. 30). Chazal tell us that before setting off to
>   save the captives, he composed the immortal kapitol we recite every
>   *Elul and Tishrei, Hashem is my light and my salvation, from whom shall I fear [Tehillim
>   27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16248)*. After
>   overtaking the captors, he struck them from twilight until the next
>   evening and not one of them escaped except for four hundred young men
>   who rode on camels and fled, and rescued all his kidnapped family and
>   followers. None was missing of them [the captives] from young to old,
>   sons or daughters, or from the spoil and all that they took for
>   themselves. Dovid returned everything (verse 17).

[Tehillim 27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16248)

> לְדָוִ֨ד | יְהֹוָ֚ה | אוֹרִ֣י וְ֖יִשְׁעִי מִמִּ֣י אִירָ֑א יְהֹוָ֖ה
>   מָע֥וֹז חַ֜יַּ֗י מִמִּ֥י אֶפְחָֽד:
>
> Of David. The Lord is my light and my salvation; whom shall I fear?
>   The Lord is the stronghold of my life; from whom shall I be
>   frightened?

The source for the above referenced Chazal ([Pessikta Rabatti, ch. 8](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) reads as follows:

> ד"א ה' אורי וישעי כנגד מי אמרו דוד... וריב"ל [אמר] כנגד גדוד עמלק אמרו כמ"ש ויהי בבוא דוד ואנשיו צקלג ביום השלישי ועמלקי פשטו [וגו'] וישבו כל אשר בה וגו' (שמואל א' ל' א' וב') וישאל דוד בה' הארדוף אחרי הגדוד הזה (שם שם) וימצאו איש מצרי [וגו'] (שם שם י"א) ויורידהו והנה נטושים על פני [וגו'] (שם שם ט"ז) ויכם דוד מהנשף ועד הערב למחרתם (שם שם י"ז) למחרת אין כתיב כאן אלא עד למחרתם שהיה מכה בהם ג' ימים שנאמר ויכם דוד מהנשף ועד הערב הרי אחד עד למחרת הרי שני ימים

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that might be what I saw referenced. I was hoping that there would be a Chazal or Perek of Tehillim that says about David's reaction when they came to Ziklag. Because in Shmuel 1; 30,6 it says: ויתחזק דוד בה' אלקיו. I understand it to mean that in this Extremely hard/overwhelming situation, he was mechazek his Emunah/Bitachon in HaShem, thereby finding strength to dealing with the situation, instead of caving in to despair and giving up. (I guess I would also be happy if there's any Sefarim that talk about this point.) Thank you to all of you!

Comment: @Ari OK if you think that this is the correct answer, click the check mark next to the answer to show that you accept it.

Comment: Will people still view this question (and possibly help) after I put a check on his answer?

Comment: @Ari yes, many questions get multiple answers (with upvotes) even with a check mark on one of them.